# How to create 404.blade.php with default filomentphp design?

Tags: laravel-filament

My laravel/livewire sites has resources/views/errors/404.blade.php with structure like :

```
@extends('layouts.frontpage')

@section('content')

    <div >

    </div>

@endsection
```

where file consists of html tags and php-blade commands.

How can I create such file with filamentphp, based on standard layout / design and possibility to show custom messages?

I created manually file resources/views/errors/404.blade.php - it is rendered, but it has no default filomentphp design. How can I implement it ?

```
"filament/filament": "^2.17.17",
"filament/forms": "^2.17.17",
"laravel/framework": "^9.52.4",
```

Thanks in advance!